# Generate CSV file with some values quoted and others not

Tags: java, kotlin, opencsv

I am new to writing CSV files and have a scenario I can't find answers on. I need to generate a CSV file with no headers where number values are not quoted, strings are quoted. An example would be - 71,72, "initial","2020-10-01".

I used the CSVWriter Constructor of:

```
CSVWriter(FileWriter(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("mytable.csv").path), ',', '\'', '\"', "\n")
```

I tried to populate my string values with double quotes as so but this does not work.

```
val linesForCSVUploadToTable = arrayOf(
                    someId.toString(),
                    someOtherId.toString(),
                    "\"initial\"",
                    "\"2020-10-15\"",
                    "\"2020-10-15\"",
                    "\"csv\"",//created_by
                    "\"2020-10-15\"",
                    "\"csv\"",
                    "\"csv\"",
                    "\"2020-10-15\""
            )
```

The output is:

```
'100001','100001','""initial""','""2020-10-15""','""2020-10-15""','""csv""','""2020-10-15""','""csv""','""csv""','""2020-10-15""'
```

I have to .toString the ids because the writeAll() and writeNext() functions appear to take a String Array and an array of type ANY isn't accepted.

I want to avoid writing my own custom CSV writer. If I have to then so be it.

I am using OpenCSV 5.2 and writing this in Kotlin. Java also works.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This is an odd requirement... [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) defines when and how to quote, so why would you deviate from that? Unless you're dealing with a non-conformant CSV reader?

Comment: Do you mean that some of the values you're storing should include quotes, regardless of how they're stored? (That's perfectly understandable — but the CSV writer and reader should take care of all that for you.) Or do you mean that the resulting CSV file should have some values quoted and others not? (I'm not aware of any good reason for doing that. As Robert says, it's very non-standard, and may well indicate a misunderstanding somewhere. Whether you quote fields or not, the end result would normally be the same.)

Comment: @Robert i guess its a non-conformant CSV reader? This CSV is going to bulk upload ~50 million rows into my AWS Aurora Postgres DB and the CSV rows have to match up to your table structure, with mine being - BigInt, BigInt, String, etc. This CSV Reader in AWS I guess doesn't parse Strings to Ints?

Comment: @gidds I need numbers to not be quoted and Strings to be quoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/QuoteMode.html#NON_NUMERIC), which provides the `NON_NUMERIC` quoting strategy and thus quotes any non-numeric value in your CSV file. **Example:**

```java
try (Writer w = ...) {
    CSVFormat outFormat = CSVFormat.newFormat(',')
        .withRecordSeparator("\n")
        .withQuote('\"')
        .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL);
    CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(w, outFormat);
    printer.printRecords(...);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you for this!